# How to add block title section and color without the title in beamer?

Tags: beamer, block

When I empty the block title in beamer it doesn't show the green color in Madrid theme. I want to get this color although when I empty the title as well as when give a title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `\relax` as title and if needed, also as subtitle:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\relax}%>>>
  No title in Madrid.
\end{frame}%<<<

\begin{frame}{\relax}{\relax}%>>>
  No title in Madrid.
\end{frame}%<<<

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\relax` doesn't work for a `block` environment. But for this you could use `\strut` or (if that is to big) `\phantom{phantom Title}` or something like that.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\relax}%>>>
  No title in Madrid.
  \begin{block}{\phantom{Tp}}
    Block without Title
  \end{block}
\end{frame}%<<<

\begin{frame}{\relax}{\relax}%>>>
  No title in Madrid.
\end{frame}%<<<

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes `\phantom{Tp}` works. No need `\relax`

Comment: @alhelal at first I thought you meant the frame titles. It would have been better if you'd included a MWE in your question.

Comment: I also said `block title` and yes I should add a MWE. I guessed  the code  might be very simple, so I didn't add MWE.

Comment: @alhelal A MWE would have made your question way less confusing - especially as green is not the default colour of ordinary blocks in `Madrid`. Even if the code is simple, it saves everybody trying to help you to start from scratch.

Comment: @samcarter Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Skillmon `phantom{Tp}` fulfills my requirement. But, What does `\relax` do?

Comment: @alhelal `\relax` does nothing by itself, but it is not an empty argument to the frame title, so the beamer template for the frame title gets displayed/used. It doesn't work for a `block` because those evaluate the size of the title and since `\relax` has no size...

Answer (score 2):

If you want this behaviour for all blocks, you could change the definition of `block begin` to include an invisible element of whatever height the blue title area should have.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=block title,lower=block body,shadow=true]%
    {\raggedright\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle
     \rule{0pt}{0.6em}%
    }%
    \raggedright%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{}
test
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```